# Unity Canvas does not fill screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I have a 2D game set to 1080p pixel size (so each unit equals 1 pixel) and I have added a canvas to my scene. However the canvas fills only about 1/8th of the screen and is also not central either. All the canvas size and position settings are locked so I cant move it or resize it. The canvas itself does reflect the screen (ie if I put text in the top right corner it appears correctly) but the size makes it hard to judge where best to position the elements).

How do I get the canvas to fill my scene?

[image: Image showing canvas in my scene]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of your Canvas' inspector? Maybe it helps to understand problem

Comment: I have added a capture of the inspector

Comment: add a shot of the rendered frame window please

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On your canvas, set the `Canvas Scaler` component's `Ui Scale Mode` to `Scale with Screen Size`. Then you can define a `Reference Resolution` of 1080p, i.e. 1920 x 1080.

**EDIT:** To see the canvas fit into the camera's size in the scene, change the `Canvas` component's `Render Mode` to `Screen Space - Camera`, and drag the camera from the hierarchy to it.

([check this video](https://youtu.be/dCJGjMzcwwU))

Comment: I made the changes to the settings you suggested but nothing appears to have happened. I have posted an image of the inspector above.

Comment: @coolblue2000 Answer edited to include fitting the canvas inside the scene camera's size.

Comment: It did not work at all

Answer (score 0):

[image: See this image]

By default the image position in rect transformation (e.g left top etc) have some value make it 0 for everything and for pivot as well, worked for me;

P.S. render mode for canvas should be screen space - overlay